# Helper in CPP or H

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Suppose I have a helper:

```
namespace test
{
    void doSomething() 
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Should I put that code in a .cpp file or .h file, so I can then #Include it?

Comment: Totally depends. An itty-bitty function like a bit of simple one-liner math that's unlikely to ever change I might make `inline` and leave in the header (the `inline` is very important. See [ODR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule)). Anything complicated or prone to change I'll implement in the CPP file.

Comment: I misinterpreted the question slightly and only addressed the function. Assuming this helper is to be used by more than one [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)), I would declare in the header (possibly define--see comment 1). If only one translation unit uses the helper, it goes in the cpp file with the rest of the code that uses the helper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a declaration needs to be seen by multiple files, put it in a header. If a declaration is needed in only one file, put it in that file (probably in an anonymous namespace to reduce the chance of name clashes).

A function definition usually does not go in a header file unless you want to give the compiler a chance to inline it. The less you put in a header file, the less mental overhead it takes for a programmer to use that file (similarly for compilers, but I have more sympathy for programmers).

Comment: What do I do for functions that are helpers? Do I put it in a CPP file? A header file? A anonymous namespace in a cpp file?

Comment: @BiBi Don't think in terms of "helper". Is the function needed in more than one file?

Comment: Yes, the function is.

Comment: @BiBi Then the function's declaration needs to be seen by multiple files. See my answer. As for the *definition*, that is needed to be seen by multiple files only if you expect it to be inlined.